# ASP.NET MVC Selected Value change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectedvalue

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project.

Here is code I've been stuck on:

```
<select>
    <option asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Catalog" asp-route-id="1" >Fish</option>
    <option asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Catalog" asp-route-id="2">Rodent</option>
</select>

<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Catalog" asp-route-id="2">Click to show Category num 2</a>
```

The `<a>` tag is working, while the select doesn't.

I've tried to put it on form with Submit button and still not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: _"The <a> tag is working, while the select doesn't."_ What does "working" mean? What do you expect should happen? What happens instead? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is that message?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, the <a> tag working means that it's send the asp-route-id"1" to 'id' at Action Catalog, it's make the catalog to show only Catalog num 1, but when I use the option (what I really need) it's not showing me Catalog num 2.

Answer (score 1):

Those asp tag helpers you are using won't do anything for `<option>` elements. You'll need to submit a form and give them a `value`. Your `<select>` also needs a `name` attribute so your action can bind to a variable.

Your form:

```
<form id="myForm" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Catalog" method="get">
    <select name="id">
        <option value="1">Fish</option>
        <option value="2">Rodent</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Catalog(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

If you want to automatically send when the select changes, you'll need JavaScript. The easiest is to submit the form with js.

Add an event handler to the element

```
<select name="id" onchange="handleChange()">
    <option value="1">Fish</option>
    <option value="2">Rodent</option>
</select>
```

And define the even handler

```
function handleChange() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

Another option is to listen for the event and make an AJAX request instead of doing a form submission.

Vanilla JavaScript and jQuery examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247483/2030565).

Comment: Hi! Thank you it's worked, by the way can I make the Select to submit with out a Sumbit button? Just that the select will be.